# Cannot register spring microservice with netflix eureka

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I have the maven spring microservice with main class.

```
@EnableEncryptableProperties
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class AccountService {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(AccountService.class, args);
    }

}
```

In my pom.xml I added following dependencies for registering app.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

During startup I get the following error.

```
[WARN ] 2021-01-11 22:05:50 [main] AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.microservices.accountservice.AccountService]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
[ERROR] 2021-01-11 22:05:50 [main] SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.microservices.accountservice.AccountService]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

The project has defined the following spring version.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Moreover microservice during startup communicates using bootstrap.properties with spring-cloud-config-server to fetch application.properties. What could be the issue related with this error ?

Comment: you can't mix version of spring cloud. The 1.x versions aren't compatible with the 2.x versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependencies in your `pom.xml` are not compatible with each other. You should use [`spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:2.2.6.RELEASE`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client/2.2.6.RELEASE/jar).

It is even better if you don't specify the versions for each of your dependencies but you use the BOM (`spring-cloud-dependencies`), see the [official guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/).